# Can i delete all of my YouTube channel videos and start creating new content on a different category but on the same channel? Will it get monitized?

Tags: youtube

I want to change my YouTube channel niche and start creating content on a different category on the same channel that i currently have. The reason why i decided doing this is because my current channel is suspended from getting approved for YouTube Partner Program (YPP) and i believe that YouTube Won't accept any possible appeal i make. So by deleting all of my previous videos and uploading new content on a new category, will my channel be able to reapply for YPP and get approved for monitization?